# How to solve unauthorized error when installing ssl certificate with certbot?

Tags: php, docker, ssl, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt

I am trying to install ssl certificate on a specific domain with letsencrypt but I am getting below error every time.

```
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for subdomain.domain.com
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. subdomain.domain.com (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://subdomain.domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/QjvSK-sa8wFxqxiZoqHBgQNx8x2O0NsojTOQ-_SSS7Q [167.99.94.47]: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n    <head>\n        <meta charset=\"UTF-8\" />\n        <meta name=\"robots\" content=\"noindex,nofollow\" />\n   "

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: subdomain.domain.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://subdomain.domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/QjvSK-sa8wFxqxiZoqHBgQNx8x2O0NsojTOQ-_SSS7Q
   [167.99.94.47]: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n    <head>\n        <meta
   charset=\"UTF-8\" />\n        <meta name=\"robots\"
   content=\"noindex,nofollow\" />\n   "

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

My website that using this domain is php project that running on docker and it is hosting on digitalocean droplet.

I make all domain redirects and domain redirection is working. But not ssl.

How can manage this problem?

Could you help me with this?

Comment: If you are doing any URL rewriting, make sure `/.well-known/` is not affected by that. You need to add an exception that lets these requests pass through unchanged, if they are getting routed to your own app or anything like that, this can’t work.